# Why am I getting Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'x' was corrupted?

Tags: c++, mfc

This is driving me crazy. I have legacy code where I added few more conditions (below). I am parsing a string and retrieving the data. This is how it is done in legacy code so I haven't changed the style.

```
        WORD wPSM = 0;
        double dblPST = 0;
        WORD wSDB = 0;

        if(-1 != str.Find("PSM="))
        {
            nNumScanned = sscanf_s((LPCTSTR) str, "PSM=%u", &wPSM);
        }
        if(-1 != str.Find("PST="))
        {
            nNumScanned = sscanf_s((LPCTSTR) str, "PST=%lf", &dblPST);
        }
        if(-1 != str.Find("SDB="))
        {
            nNumScanned = sscanf_s((LPCTSTR) str, "SDB=%u", &wSDB);
        }
```

I get error `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'wPSM' was corrupted`. I don't get this error if I commented these three lines. `str` is CString and it does contain the expected value.

Is there something wrong with `sscanf_s` syntax above that maybe causing this?

Note this is c++ project with VS2010, I have marked it C only to draw attention because of sscanf_s

Comment: There is no `wPST` variable in the code you show.

Comment: a) which 3 lines?
b) where is wPST declared, it's not in your snippet

Comment: You're scanning with `%u` (and so, likely, collecting 32 bits of data - if not 64 bits) into a `WORD` (16-bit) variable. Those extra 16 bits are going into a part of the stack where they don't belong.

Comment: Bit OT, but I don't think the C tag is relevant despite your usage of `sscanf_s`. First, it's a Windows-specific function, and second, this *is* C++ code.

Comment: corrected wPST reference, sorry had shortened the actual names for public post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`WORD` is a define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) for a 16 bits unsigned integer, so your program has **undefined behaviour** since `sscanf_s` expects an unsigned integer.

You need the `%hu` modifier in your calls to `sscanf_s`.